# How to set appropriate x-axis scale

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I wrote a function to plot 3 graphs from different dicts, however the dicts can change depending on which json file the user choose, so the code should be able to adjust the x axis scale somehow on its own (the x-axis is date).

But when I try to run the code I get something like this

[image: current output]

Here is my code to plot

```
def plot_averages(morning_dict , night_dict, hourly_dict):
    plt.plot(morning_dict.keys() , morning_dict.values() ,"r*",  label = "Daily mean")
    plt.plot(night_dict.keys() , night_dict.values() ,"b*",  label = "Night mean")
    plt.plot(hourly_dict.keys(), hourly_dict.values() , "g." ,   label = "Hourly value")
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel("Value")
    plt.title(file_name)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

And those are the values plotted in figure above (sample since it's pretty long)

```
hourly_dict =
{'2022-05-12 06:00:00': 11.8,
 '2022-05-12 18:00:00': 12.5,
 '2022-05-13 06:00:00': 10.9,
 '2022-05-13 18:00:00': 13.5,
 '2022-05-14 06:00:00': 11.8,
 '2022-05-14 18:00:00': 15.1,
 '2022-05-15 06:00:00': 11.7,
 '2022-05-15 18:00:00': 13.2,
 '2022-05-16 06:00:00': 12.1,
 '2022-05-16 18:00:00': 10.2,
 '2022-05-17 06:00:00': 11.0,
 '2022-05-17 18:00:00': 10.0,
 '2022-05-18 06:00:00': 10.0,
 '2022-05-18 18:00:00': 16.6,
 '2022-05-19 06:00:00': 12.7,
 '2022-05-19 18:00:00': 21.3,
 '2022-05-20 06:00:00': 15.1,
 '2022-05-20 18:00:00': 11.6,
 '2022-05-21 06:00:00': 8.2,}
```

```
Morning_dict =
{'2022-06-01 06:00:00': 11.7,
 '2022-07-01 06:00:00': 21.6,
 '2022-08-01 06:00:00': 15.3,
 '2022-09-01 06:00:00': 11.3,
 '2022-06-02 06:00:00': 12.0,
 '2022-07-02 06:00:00': 17.2,
 '2022-08-02 06:00:00': 15.2,
 '2022-09-02 06:00:00': 12.1,
 '2022-06-03 06:00:00': 13.6,
 '2022-07-03 06:00:00': 18.5,
 '2022-08-03 06:00:00': 18.9,
 '2022-09-03 06:00:00': 9.2,
 '2022-06-04 06:00:00': 13.7,
 '2022-07-04 06:00:00': 16.5,
 '2022-08-04 06:00:00': 21.6,
 '2022-09-04 06:00:00': 13.5,
 '2022-06-05 06:00:00': 17.0,
 '2022-07-05 06:00:00': 16.3,
 '2022-08-05 06:00:00': 19.7,
 '2022-09-05 06:00:00': 8.7,
 '2022-06-06 06:00:00': 16.2,
 '2022-07-06 06:00:00': 15.6,
 '2022-08-06 06:00:00': 14.3,
 '2022-09-06 06:00:00': 5.9,
 '2022-06-07 06:00:00': 15.1,
 '2022-07-07 06:00:00': 14.9,
 '2022-08-07 06:00:00': 14.4,
 '2022-09-07 06:00:00': 8.9,
 '2022-06-08 06:00:00': 16.1,
 '2022-07-08 06:00:00': 14.1,
 '2022-08-08 06:00:00': 15.9,}
```

```
Night_dict =
{'2022-06-01 18:00:00': 13.9,
 '2022-07-01 18:00:00': 23.9,
 '2022-08-01 18:00:00': 22.0,
 '2022-09-01 18:00:00': 12.3,
 '2022-06-02 18:00:00': 15.6,
 '2022-07-02 18:00:00': 21.8,
 '2022-08-02 18:00:00': 21.9,
 '2022-09-02 18:00:00': 11.3,
 '2022-06-03 18:00:00': 15.2,
 '2022-07-03 18:00:00': 21.9,
 '2022-08-03 18:00:00': 26.1,
 '2022-06-04 18:00:00': 18.2,
 '2022-07-04 18:00:00': 20.9,
 '2022-08-04 18:00:00': 27.0,
 '2022-06-05 18:00:00': 22.9,
 '2022-07-05 18:00:00': 19.7,}
```

Since you can see the `hourly_dict` is split into 2 dicts, morning and night, and therefore it should be showing twice as much points in the graph, but there are somehow equally number of points for all of them overlapping. I guess the problem is the x-axis scale. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you will need to do. First, convert the dates in the 3 dictionaries to `datetime` format. This will allow matplotlib to set the dates in the correct order as well as let you format the axis.

Then, once you plot, you can use `set_major_formatter` and `set_major_locator` to adjust how many ticks you want. Optionally, you can also use `autofmt_xdate()` to let matplot adjust/rotate the labels as needed. Please see the below code. I have used the ticks for one in 14 days. You can change it to higher/lower number or even do a month format (check out the commented code). Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
## Assuming you already have the 3 dictionaries above
from datetime import datetime
## Convert each dictionary value to datetime
hourly_dict = {datetime.strptime(key, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"): val for key, val in hourly_dict.items()}
morning_dict = {datetime.strptime(key, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"): val for key, val in morning_dict.items()}
night_dict = {datetime.strptime(key, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"): val for key, val in night_dict.items()}

##Plot graph - no change here
plt.plot(morning_dict.keys() , morning_dict.values() ,"r*",  label = "Daily mean")
plt.plot(night_dict.keys() , night_dict.values() ,"b*",  label = "Night mean")
plt.plot(hourly_dict.keys(), hourly_dict.values() , "g." ,   label = "Hourly value")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.title('file_name')

## Tell how many days gap should be between each tick (14 days here) - month in comment
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=14))   #to get a tick every 14 days
#plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))   #to get a tick once a month

#How should the tick labels appear - DD-MM-YYY here
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))     #How the date format looks
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()  ##Let matplotlib autoformat x-dates
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]